# Finding difference of count of records using aggregation

Tags: python, django

I'm given a task to write this code into one query using aggregation/annotation.

I tried using the count and stuff but I don't have any idea how this works

```
upvotes = UserVote.objects.filter(blog=self, vote_type='U').count()
downvotes = UserVote.objects.filter(blog=self, vote_type='D').count()
return upvotes - downvotes
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation for `aggregate` and `annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/)? It contains many examples which include exactly what you're trying to do. Especially the last example of the cheat sheet should put you on the right track.

Comment: @dirkgroten I just saw it again but it's a bit complicated for me.
Can you please elaborate and use the example that I mentioned above?

Comment: `Publisher` is your `Blog` and `Book` is your `UserVote`.

Comment: @dirkgroten I've been working on it for hours but I can't find a working command. Can you please help me?

Comment: Anyways, I did it using this:

`return Blog.objects.aggregate(total_votes=(Count('post_votes', filter=Q(post_votes__vote_type='U') & Q(post_votes__blog=self)) - Count('post_votes', filter=Q(post_votes__vote_type='D') & Q(post_votes__blog=self))))
`

Would've been better if someone helped properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyways, I did it using this:

`return Blog.objects.aggregate(total_votes=(Count('post_votes', filter=Q(post_votes__vote_type='U') & Q(post_votes__blog=self)) - Count('post_votes', filter=Q(post_votes__vote_type='D') & Q(post_votes__blog=self))))`